# How to filter Sub-categories with "in" clause in Entity framework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to implement following query of SQL in entity framework:-

Select * from Categories where parentid in (select id from Categories where CategoryName='Super')

I am trying to get sub-categories from CategoryName and binding to repeater control, C#

Thanks,

Tried:
var _db = new CatalogueContext();
IQueryable query = _db.Categories;

query = query.Where(p => String.Compare(p.CategoryName, categoryName) == 0);

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ query finds the ID of the category with the name "Super", then finds all categories whose ParentID matches, then binds to a repeater:

```
var subcategories = context.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentID == context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == "Super").ID).ToList();

Repeater1.DataSource = subcategories;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```